# How to set a hint when the user leaves the text-box empty and tries to proceed?

Tags: android

I am trying to set a hint when a user leaves the text-box empty and tries to proceed by  clicking the centre key, but am getting an error on one of the semi_colons.

Here is my code:

```
    String defaultName = "";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras!=null) {
        defaultName = extras.getString("Name");  
        EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        txt.setHint(defaultName);
    } else {      

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {          

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is pretty much unclear, paste full code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

use it in this way:

```
if(defaultName == null)
      defaultName = "dont leave it blank";

txtBox.setHint(defaultName);
```

Comment: when the user have entered value,then??..Have your thought for that case?

Comment: Hints are only displayed when there is no values. That's how they work. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be if the text is blank, then have the EditText request focus. This will move the screen to it and will highlight it. The hint **should STAY constant** otherwise you're going to confuse the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button while there is no text.I think something like this should work:

```
    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Overrride
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            weiter_fertig.setEnabled(s.length() > 0);

        }
    });
```